# SQL Server/TSQL : Aliasing a column on table alias in join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax, alias

For efficiency, I'm trying to find out if there is a syntax which allows me to alias a column on a table using that table alias entirely in the from section and join sections.

I know I could alias the column in the SELECT, but if I were using select * (I know, not good practice) it would not be available. I boiled down an example to show how I'd like to refer to the column name (`doubleAlias`):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table1] AS tl
   JOIN [table2] AS t2
   ON t1.[column1] = t2.[column1] AS doubleAlias
    WHERE doubleAlias = 'value';
--INSTEAD OF
  --WHERE t2.[column1] = 'value';
```

Comment: Nope...........

Comment: You could do an apply statement instead of a join if you REALLY wanted to alias before the select.

Comment: What is your goal? The question was written asking how a certain task (not really possible ) can be attained, though you _should_ mention what it is that you're trying to accomplish (i.e. what is wrong with having `WHERE t2.[column1] = 'value' `).

Comment: I profile a lot of program generated code and typically work within the confines of the where clause. There are often times pre-established table aliases and asked the question for the purposes stated; efficiency and potential lack of knowledge regarding syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM [table1] tl JOIN
     [table2] t2
     ON t1.[column1] = t2.[column1] OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES (t1.column1) ) v(doubleAlias)
WHERE doubleAlias = 'value';
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just give you column1 a 3rd time? Why OUTER APPLY instead of CROSS APPLY if using an inner join?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock . . . I understand the first question.  That is simply the use of `select *`.  I switched to selecting from the two tables.  As for `outer apply` versus `apply` . . . either words.  I chose `outer apply` simply because it emphasizes that all rows from the first table are kept, regardless of the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the table in a CTE where you can assign new column names.

```
WITH t2 AS (
    SELECT *, column1 AS doubleAlias
    FROM [table2] 
)
SELECT *
FROM [table1] AS tl
JOIN t2
   ON t1.[column1] = t2.[doubleAlias]
WHERE t2.doubleAlias = 'value';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two methods of double aliasing a column, just not with the syntax you chose.

1. Consider replacing table2 with a view, you can alias the columns as much as you want within the view.
2. Consider a sub query, so replace table2 with another select statement

   select *
   from A join
   (SELECT Col1 ColAlias from B) C 
   on A.ColName = ColAlias